# How to handle the error and success notification in a common way(middleware) using RTK Query?

Tags: react-redux, rtk-query

I am new to RTK queries, and I like to work with RTK queries.

In my project, I would like to add a common error handler(middleware) also a success response handler. For error handling, I found a middleware utility from RTK query documentation. Using **isRejectedWithValue** we can handle the common errors. But for success API requests, I didn't find any utility.

Please let me know if anyone has more context on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
import { isRejectedWithValue, isFulfilled } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import type { MiddlewareAPI, Middleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { toast } from 'your-cool-library'

export const rtkQueryLogger: Middleware =
  (api: MiddlewareAPI) => (next) => (action) => {
    // RTK Query uses `createAsyncThunk` from redux-toolkit under the hood, so we're able to utilize these matchers!
    if (isRejectedWithValue(action)) {
      console.warn('We got a rejected action!')
      toast.warn({ title: 'Async error!', message: action.error.data.message })
    } else (isFulfilled(action)) {
      toast.success('It worked!');
    }

    return next(action)
  }
```

Based on the example from rtk query docs:

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/error-handling#handling-errors-at-a-macro-level

Answer (score -2):

I believe that `isFulfilled` is what you are looking for
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities#isfulfilled